# Error while sending email from android app using SendGrid

Tags: android, apache-httpclient-4.x, sendgrid

In my app am trying to send email using send grid.

In my doInBackground method of AsyncTask I have the below code

```
            SendGrid sendgrid = new SendGrid("XXXXXX", "YYYYYY");
            publishProgress("Preparing mail message....");
            SendGrid.Email email = new SendGrid.Email();
            email.setFrom(args[0].toString());
            email.addTo(args[2].toString());
            email.setSubject(args[3].toString());
            email.setText(args[4].toString());
            // androidEmail.createEmailMessage();
            publishProgress("Sending email....");
            try {
                sendgrid.send(email);
            } catch (SendGridException e) {
                System.out.println(e);
                Log.i("SendGrid Exception", "Mail Not Sent.");
            }
            publishProgress("Email Sent.");
```

When I runt his I get the below error :

```
 Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchFieldError:        org.apache.http.message.BasicLineFormatter.INSTANCE
 at org.apache.http.impl.io.DefaultHttpRequestWriterFactory.<init>(DefaultHttpRequestWriterFactory.java:52)
 at org.apache.http.impl.io.DefaultHttpRequestWriterFactory.<init>(DefaultHttpRequestWriterFactory.java:56)
 at org.apache.http.impl.io.DefaultHttpRequestWriterFactory.<clinit>(DefaultHttpRequestWriterFactory.java:46)
 at org.apache.http.impl.conn.ManagedHttpClientConnectionFactory.<init>(ManagedHttpClientConnectionFactory.java:72)
 at org.apache.http.impl.conn.ManagedHttpClientConnectionFactory.<init>(ManagedHttpClientConnectionFactory.java:84)
 at org.apache.http.impl.conn.ManagedHttpClientConnectionFactory.<clinit>(ManagedHttpClientConnectionFactory.java:59)
 at   org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager$InternalConnectionFactory.  <init>(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:493)
 at org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.<init>(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:149)
 at org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.<init>(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:138)
 at org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.<init>(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:114)
 at org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClientBuilder.build(HttpClientBuilder.java:726)
 at com.sendgrid.SendGrid.<init>(SendGrid.java:59)
```

I downdload the send-grod.jar from their github page. I tested it with sample java program and I could send mail successfully. But it is not working in Android.

What am I missing.?

Comment: And which is the line in your code that is failing. Can you add the full stack trace error?

Comment: at com.category.xxxxxxxx.EmailActivity$SendMailTask.doInBackground(EmailActivity.java:159)

i.e; at line 
        SendGrid sendgrid = new SendGrid("XXXXXX", "YYYYYY");

Comment: Have you tried to do this example and using the same jars? https://github.com/thinkingserious/sendgrid-android-example

Comment: Be careful with this. If you distribute this, your SendGrid username and password will be on many devices. Two problems. If you ever change your SendGrid password, no one will be able to send without an update to the app. Secondly, anyone with a decompiler will see the credentials. Then be able to send email and possibly login to your SendGrid account. I highly recommend putting this behind a web service of some sort to prevent abuse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understood the reason for the behaviour.

Some of the dependcy libraries used by the send-grid will not work on android.

So I used maven to build my own jar with all the requried libraries which works on android.

Finally I could send email from my app.

The two links : [first](http://blog.mashape.com/using-unirest-java-for-your-android-projects/)! and  [second](http://blog.mashape.com/installing-unirest-java-with-the-maven-assembly-plugin/)!  were helpful.